# Getting exif orientation of img element and assigning class accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, css, orientation, exif

I have an image element and I need to change the rotation of the image based on the exif orientation. I need to do so using javascript only.

The following are the css classes:

```
.image_up {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.image_down {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.image_left {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

And this is the logic of assigning the css to the image file:

```
{
    case 3: // 180 rotate left
        document.getElementById("user-avatar").className = "image_up";
        break;
    case 6: // 90 rotate right
        document.getElementById("user-avatar").className = "image_down";
        break;
    case 8: // 90 rotate left
        document.getElementById("user-avatar").className = "image_left";
        break;
}
```

My issue is in obtaining the exif data of the image file and selecting the proper class before showing the image

Comment: Github has a javascript library for extracting exif information https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

Comment: yes I am using that library and I need to run locally but it is not working. Does it only work when running the code from server?

Comment: The file runs in the browser. Make sure that you have the correct path to the js file. You can look at the console error panel (press F12 in the browser to bring up the developer tools panel). Any errors in your code should be displayed in the console panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vue.js
you can simply use this `vue-img-orientation-changer` to fix the incorrect img orientation.

`vue-img-orientation-changer` is a vue directive plugin.

Check the example: 
[Fix Img Orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvSgl.png)

Github Repository: [vue-img-orientation-changer](https://github.com/nikli2009/vue-img-orientation-changer)